# Как создать словарь из списка цифр?

Tags: python, list, словари

Цель: Создать словарь на основе списка.
Разделитель число от 265 до 265, это отрезок из которого формируется новый словарь.

```
[**265**, 210, 20, 10, 13, 2, 4, 2, 8, 6, 360, 230, 9, 5, 12, 2, 10, 10, 36, 14, 64, 62, 7, 1, 72, 14, **265**, 211, 20, 11, 13, 3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 360, 51, 9, 6, 12, 3, 10, 1, 36, 15, 64, 27, 7, 7, 72, 51]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно преобразовать список в словарь, где

```
{'265': 210, '20':10,....}
```

Comment: в вашем примере никак не видно что должен делать разделитель

Comment: По разделителю, определяем отрезок из которого нужно сформировать отдельный словарь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def add(dt):
    while True:
        key = yield
        value = yield
        dt[key] = value

lst = [31, 265, 210, 20, 10, 265, 211, 21, 11, 1, 2, 3, 265, 211, 22, 12, 12345]
res = []
for i in lst:
    if i == 265:
        res.append({})
        a = add(res[-1])
        next(a)
    try: a.send(i)
    except NameError: continue
print(res)  # [{265: 210, 20: 10}, {265: 211, 21: 11, 1: 2}, {265: 211, 22: 12}]
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Если только два таких разделителя, то примерно так:

```
lst = [265, 210, 20, 10, 13, 2, 4, 2, 8, 6, 360, 230, 9, 5, 12, 2, 10, 10, 36, 14, 64, 62, 7, 1, 72, 14, 265, 211, 20, 11, 13, 3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 360, 51, 9, 6, 12, 3, 10, 1, 36, 15, 64, 27, 7, 7, 72, 51]

i1 = lst.index(265) + 1
i2 = lst.index(265, i1)
lst12 = lst[i1:i2]
d = dict(zip(lst12[::2],lst12[1::2]))
print(d)
```

Вывод:

```
{210: 20, 10: 36, 2: 10, 6: 360, 230: 9, 5: 12, 14: 64, 62: 7, 1: 72}
```

При этом элемент списка `14` не попал в словарь, потому что у него не было пары, чтобы образовать `ключ: значение`.

Если разделителей больше - ну сделать цикл на основе данного кода, взяв `lst = lst[i2+1:]`.

Answer (score 1):

в примере никак не показан разделитель (что с ним делать)

без этого код может выглядеть так:

```
arr = [265, 210, 20, 10, 13, 2, 4, 2, 8, 6, 360, 230, 9, 5, 12, 2, 10, 10, 36, 14, 64, 62, 7, 1, 72, 14,]

res = dict((str(arr[i]), arr[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(arr), 2))

print(res)
```

или так (так покороче):

```
res = dict(zip(map(str, arr[::2]), arr[1::2]))
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, а если нужно из списка нарезать словари в цикле, как это можно сделать?
`arr = arr = [265, 210, 20, 10, 13, 2, 4, 2, 8, 6, 360, 230, 9, 5, 12, 2, 10, 10, 36, 14, 64, 62, 7, 1, 72, 14,]

for res in arr:
    res = dict(zip(map(str, arr[::2]), arr[1::2]))
    print(res)`